# Ruby Net::FTP Special Chars in Filenames

Tags: ruby, ftp, special-characters

I am trying to get a file from a server which has (in this case) a comma at the end of its name.

```
#sc is my ftp connection, tmp is a Tempfile
sc.getbinaryfile(fname,tmp.path)
```

which gives me an exception `550 No such file or directory. (Net::FTPPermError)` as soon as the filename is something with comma at the end. In this concrete case `fname` was `BRr1gTuPaQ9USnybt-3F95rxD0VdQ42AT0rS4MeYSPIs2,`. I have also tried connecting to the server via my FTP-Client - the file definitely exists and can be downloaded.

Do I have to escape this special chars like comma or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I explicitly tried this sc.getbinaryfile("BRr1gTuPaQ9USnybt-3F95rxD0VdQ42AT0rS4MeYSPIs2,") and it worked without any problems. Which version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: Mac OS, Linux doesn't matter which - exact same behavior on both of them.

Comment: Do you have access to the FTP logs? What FTP server are you using? I just tried this as well (happened to be using JRuby 1.7.0 and ProFTPd), and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

What if you did..`sc.genbinaryfile("#{fname}",tmp.path)`